# No error on incorrect macro definition

Tags: c++

While replacing macros with constexpr auto I came across the following macro

```
#define MSG_SELECTED_INSPECTION [OF D] 490
```

This has been in the project forever and it compiles just fine.

Removing the space however

```
#define MSG_SELECTED_INSPECTION[OF D] 490
```

emits the error `'[':unexpected macro definition`

How come no error is emitted on the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are largely a text replacement facility. `#define MSG_SELECTED_INSPECTION [OF D] 490` is a perfectly valid macro definition. Whenever `MSG_SELECTED_INSPECTION` is seen, it will be replaced by `[OF D] 490`.

The reason `#define MSG_SELECTED_INSPECTION[OF D] 490` is because the definition must be separated from the macro name by at least a space. This is because not all compilers allow the same set of characters in identifiers, and it would be harmful if

```
#define A$B C
```

would define a macro `A` as expanding to `$B C` on one implementation, and a macro `A$B` as expanding to `C` on another.

Comment: It's worth noting that two other things which definitely do terminate the name of the macro are an opening parenthesis, or a newline.

Comment: *token replacement facility

Comment: @StoryTeller True, but I didn't want to needlessly confuse. Token replacement facility is just text replacement facility with "whole words only" checked, for a suitable definition of word. :)

Comment: I must say, it feels almost unclean to consider `A$B` as a valid identifier. But TIL.

Answer (score 2):

Macro is text replacement.

So before, you replace `MSG_SELECTED_INSPECTION` by `[OF D] 490`.
And it seems that you didn't use `MSG_SELECTED_INSPECTION` before.

Answer (score 2):

> How come no error is emitted on the first line?

A macro has two forms, function-like and object-like (what you have).

```
#define CONST ...
#define FUNC(...) ...
```

[A space is required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.replace#3) as a separator between your macro and the sequence of tokens it's defined to be replaced by. When you removed the space, it stopped being a valid (object-like) macro definition.